# Raspberry PI 3 as webserver and local router

Tags: networking, web-server

I have a small webapplication to read a small amount of simple data out of an MySQL database. I want to make this portable, easy to use and fysical as small as possible. A Raspberry PI 3 seems like a very interesting choice.

I know that the PI 3 is capable of serving as webserver and has built in WiFi.

My question here is: is it possible to use just one Raspberry PI 3 that serves as webserver and can I use the WiFi of the same PI 3 to connect my smartphone in the PI's network and access the webapplication through that wifi connection?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. I have a rpi with lamp web/database server accessible through the pi's wifi card and also allowing access to the internet while the Pi is plugged into my RG via ethernet.

Comment: Can you give more information about how to set the wireless network up?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to set up wlan is with the wpa_supplicant:

1. If you have Raspbian as OS type in:

   apt-get install wpa_supplicant
2. Create a config file for your network:

   wpa_passphrase  [ssid of your network] [passphrase/password] > /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
3. And start the connection with the created config file:

   wpa_supplicant -i [Your wireless network interface] -D wext -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -B dhcpcd wlp0s1